# full-text search in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a table (name: errors) with lots of rows. some of rows of this table shows in following:

```
202 16  Invalid type '%s' for WAITFOR. Supported data types are CHAR/VARCHAR, NCHAR/NVARCHAR, and DATETIME. WAITFOR DELAY supports the INT and SMALLINT data types.
203 16  The name '%.*ls' is not a valid identifier.
204 20  Normalization error in node %ls.
205 16  All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an  equal number of expressions in their target lists.
206 16  Operand type clash: %ls is incompatible with %ls
207 16  Invalid column name '%.*ls'.
```

instead of strings like '%.*ls', different words can be used. for example i have a string like this:

```
Invalid column name 'test'.
```

I want to use full-text search in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 to find most similar string in errors table with (Invalid column name 'test'.) i used below query but this query does not return any output

```
SELECT *
FROM errors AS A
INNER JOIN
CONTAINSTABLE(errors , text, 'ISABOUT ("Invalid column name ''text''")',
LANGUAGE N'English',10) AS K
ON A.text = K.[KEY]
```

any idea?

Comment: Try something like this. Select * From errors a Where a.text like 'Invalid column name text%' The inner join and containstable looks like overkill to me.

Comment: it does not work. "Invalid column name 'test'" does not exist in the table. 'test' is instead of '%.*ls' in the (207 16  Invalid column name '%.*ls'.) row of the table. I need to find most similar srtring!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You are searching for an error in errors that looks like Invalid column name + some other text ending in ls. Is that correct?

Comment: It was just an example. I have a table of errors. errors messages have strings like '%.*ls' that can replace with any string (for exp: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with string) I need a public way to find most similar string in the table with my string (my string: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with string or Invalid column name ''text' or ...)